# Batch Processes Python Error message

Tags: qgis

Why do I keep receiving this error message? I am using clip raster by extent as a batch process and am receiving this error each time. Any clue?

````
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.6/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\BatchAlgorithmDialog.py", line 88, in runAlgorithm
              parameters[param.name()] = wrapper.parameterValue()
             AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parameterValue'```
````

Comment: Just cant seem to get batch processing to work for any process

Comment: Could you try to create a new profile in Qgis menu -> Settings -> User profiles -> New profile

Comment: I've tried the solution proposed by Kantan, and I have the same error. Even I've uninstalled version 3.6 and installed 3.4 and the error still persists.